# How to clone SSD with Linux Mint 18 to a larger SSD

Tags: linux, disk-cloning

Is there a way to clone an SSD with Linux Mint 18 system to a larger SSD and have a functioning system? Also, what to do with GRUB?

I have multiple machines. And I plan on using one unused Linux Mint 18 desktop to plug into both SSDs, somehow copy the filesystems to the new drive.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*I searched hard for the most effective way of achieving this goal.*

My research suggests, that using [`dd`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) is a rather *deprecated* method.

In my case, as said, the target SSD drive is bigger than the source SSD. And for cloning [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) utility can be used achieving maximum speed available.

Open terminal and become [`root`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser#Unix_and_Unix-like) ([`su`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix))); if you have [`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) enabled, you may also do for example `sudo -i`; see [`man sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) for all options):

```
$ sudo -i
```

Supposing the original drive is `sdX` and the target `sdY`, create an exact copy with:

```
# pv < /dev/sdX > /dev/sdY
```

Not only it is shorter and simplier, it is faster by default with no additional settings needed, I achieved an average speed of 400MB/s with ordinary SATA SSD drives.

And as an additional benefit, it shows progress.

If you want to run this with `sudo`, you have to elaborate a little:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'pv < /dev/sdX > /dev/sdY'
```

PS: It is not true as in the other answer that man needs to install GRUB after this. All data is copied, even the boot loader.

---

### `gdisk` or `fdisk` afterwards needed

I absolutely forgot to add that I always run `gdisk` (GPT) and just do `w` for write, it always fixes necessary things. Never used MBR with Linux, so `fdisk` can't confirm, but it probably works the same.

Comment: I have ubuntu installed in legacy mode on a uefi BIOS. I tried Clonezilla many times, but, even if all was copied corrected I got problems with the grub (because of something between uefi/legacy). I finally solved with this command. thank you!!

Comment: Will this work with encrypted LVM without any changes to the approach?

Comment: @wuno Not sure, never  used LVM, neither normal, nor encrypted. Try it out and comment, please.

Comment: Any update about LUKS encrypted drives?

Comment: @Jus12 Unfortunatelly no idea, I never use encryption on my disk drives, it could complicate certain operations like this one.

Comment: What to do if I don't have two M.2 slots? I need to have an option to make an image, then apply that image to another disk.

Comment: @TedoVrbanec Why not first store an image of the original drive and then restore it onto the new one (live USB)?

Comment: That is what I asked realy: how to store image on some disk as an image and restore it to another M.2 SSD, in your way, with pv?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `dd`, the UUIDs of filesystems will remain the same.
If you create new fs, you only have to modify `/etc/fstab`.
I prefer to create new (bigger) fs, copy all files with `rsync`, then modify fstab.

Don't forget: you still have to install grub to MBR/GPT yourself after `dd` or copy!

Comment: I believe `dd` copies every bit of the source drive to the target drive.  Why would this not include the MBR/GPT?  Or does GRUB need to _modify_ the MBR/GPT?

Answer (score 0):

Sunday 15th apr 2018

I success to clone a 128GB SSD (incl LVM)  to a bigger one 256GB SSD samsung evo and install Windows 10 on a new primary partition. I want to share it with you.

tools: "live cd", gparted and a lot of patience :-). Thnaks to Kaboyish for his link about chroot/grub-update. kali & ubuntu release were from 2017.

Happy reading...

Old 128GB SSD - >256GB ssd Samsung evo

sda has kali  (using sda6) , Ubuntu (using LVM on sda5). Boot menu is kali

sdb is my new 256GB
My goal: clone kali, Ubuntu to my new 256GB Samsung ssd and having a 110GB partition for windows 10. Boot menu is still kali

1. **cloning**

```
$ fdisk –l /dev/sda
Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux    ; boot grub
/dev/sda2         1001470 250068991 249067522 118,8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5         1001472 159623167 158621696  75,7G 8e Linux LVM; Ubuntu LVM
/dev/sda6       159625216 238493695  78868480  37,6G 83 Linux    ; kali
/dev/sda7       238495744 250068991  11573248   5,5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris; swap for kali

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 60 GiB, 64424509440 bytes, 125829120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 15,6 GiB, 16785604608 bytes, 32784384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Boot your laptop from for example  “mint boot DVD”. The new ssd is connect using ssd adapter to USB.

```
mint ~ # time dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=8192 conv=notrunc,noerror
```

NB: from another session using `kill –USR1 <pid of dd>` to get progress/statistics for every 10s

```
mint ~ # watch -n10 sudo kill -USR1 $(pgrep ^dd)
990054+0 records in
990054+0 records out
8110522368 bytes (8.1 GB) copied, 183.261 s, 44.3 MB/s
2227622+0 records in
2227622+0 records out
18248679424 bytes (18 GB) copied, 412.6 s, 44.2 MB/s
6271782+0 records in
6271782+0 records out
51378438144 bytes (51 GB) copied, 1149.82 s, 44.7 MB/s
10460314+0 records in
10460314+0 records out
85690892288 bytes (86 GB) copied, 1920.88 s, 44.6 MB/s
15369910+0 records in
15369910+0 records out
125910302720 bytes (126 GB) copied, 2827.02 s, 44.5 MB/s
15629355+0 records in
15629355+0 records out
128035676160 bytes (128 GB) copied, 2874.86 s, 44.5 MB/s

real    47m54.867s
user    0m1.600s
sys     2m41.036s

mint ~ # date
Thu Apr 12 21:14:34 UTC 2018
```

Successfull, I replace the internal 128GB with the now cloned Samsung evo 256GB. It boots, I get kali grub menu as before, I choose kali, boot ok. Reboot I choose Ubuntu, boot also OK.

2. **Reorganized the partition**
   I boot from usb “gparted live cd”, remove kali swap (kali was smart it uses Ubuntu lvm swap partition when I start it) and making a new primary partition for windows ntfs, ready for win10.

```
$ lsblk 
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sda                     8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─sda4                  8:4    0   785M  0 part 
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5                  8:5    0  75,7G  0 part 
│ ├─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  15,6G  0 lvm  [SWAP]          UBUNTU
│ └─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0    60G  0 lvm  /               UBUNTU
├─sda3                  8:3    0 112,9G  0 part                 112Gb win10
├─sda1                  8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot
└─sda6                  8:6    0  43,1G  0 part                 KALI
```

3. **Install win10 on sda3**

I then install win10 on sda3, unfornutely it remove grub boot on sda, now I can only boot to win10. I need to have kali boot menu back as before.

4. **Restore the kali grub menu** (the menu will control all the boot partitions on sda)

Using chroot trick from to fix the grub issue
https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?20559-How-To-Repair-Kali-Linux-Grub-With-Kali-Linux-Live-Cd-Dual-Boot-With-Windows-7

I boot from “kali” LIVE DVD.

```
$ mount /dev/sda6 /mnt   ; my kali partition 
$ mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
$ mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
$ mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
$ mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
$ chroot /mnt                       ; if this fail check if the boot DVD is 32 or 64bit as your kali installation
$ grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

$ update-grub       ;it search for all the boot partition on the new disk sda
$ exit;  it will quit chroot 
$ umount /mnt/dev/pts
$ umount /mnt/dev
$ umount /mnt/proc
$ umount /mnt/sys
$ umount /mnt
```

stdout:  just ignore the warning about lvmetad (LVM), it boots well to all 3 OS!! Something with LVM, don’t need to do anything about this.

```
root@kali:/# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda3
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Found Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (16.04) on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
done
root@kali:/#
```

**DONE, now i have 3 OS on the new 256GB samsung.**

Nb:

change run level in kali/debian, not work!

```
root@kali:/etc# ls -l /etc/systemd/system/default.target
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jun 22  2017 /etc/systemd/system/default.target -> /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target
root@kali:/etc# ls -l /lib/systemd/system/default.target
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jun 19  2017 /lib/systemd/system/default.target -> graphical.target

root@kali:/etc# systemctl set-default graphical.target
Removed /etc/systemd/system/default.target.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target → /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target.

root@kali:/etc# ls -l /etc/systemd/system/default.target
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Apr 15 16:47 /etc/systemd/system/default.target -> /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target
```

**Change grub boot order**:
set boot-default to 3  ; work OK

```
root@kali:~# cd /etc/default/
root@kali:/etc/default# vi grub
root@kali:/etc/default# update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-kali4-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-kali3-amd64
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda3
Found Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (16.04) on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
done
root@kali:/etc/default# root@kali:~# cd /etc/default/
```

[Boot screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLRRS.png)

GOOD LUCK

Tuan CPH

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for contribution, but your answer could use a bit of formatting and trimming- you could [edit it](https://superuser.com/posts/1314294/edit) to focus on the most important bits. Cheers :)