# Cloning an SSD with pv command

Tags: linux, command-line, ssd

Can someone explain me the answer of:
[How to clone SSD with Linux Mint 18 to a larger SSD](https://superuser.com/questions/1114174/how-to-clone-ssd-with-linux-mint-18-to-a-larger-ssd)

What's up with:

```
pv < /dev/sdX > /dev/sdY
```

PV => a command for timing other command
but what is the "< source disk >" ?

I would really like to understand why this answer works.

Comment: Are you saying you don't understand what `pv` does or what?  You can copy unknown data using `dd` or you can copy to a known file system with `cp` or `rsync` or `>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many commands in Linux are designed to work in pipelines. This means you can chain them like this:

```
command1 | command2 | … | commandN
```

In this case the standard output (stdout) of `command1` goes to the standard input (stdin) of `command2` and so on. A command may or may not use its stdin/stdout, depending on its design and options+operands you provide. You can read manuals to tell which commands can work like this.

The pipe symbol (`|`) belongs to the [shell syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/108618). It's the shell what arranges connections (pipes) between commands.

In the above example `command1` has no predecessor and `commandN` has no successor in the pipe. In such case stdin of `command1` and stdout of `commandN` get connected to whatever the shell considers its stdin and stdout respectively. Usually it's the terminal.

You can change it on demand. Example:

```
command1 <input | command2 | … | commandN >output
```

`input` and `output` are files (note this is a [broad term](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)). Now if `command1` reads from its stdin then it reads from `input`; if `commandN` writes to its stdout then it writes to `output`. (More: if `command1` does anything to its stdin then it does it to `input` etc; e.g. in general it's possible to write to stdin or read from stdout because these are just file descriptors; this is rather rare, don't worry about it).

I prefer syntax that shows the data flow more clearly (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1335355/432690)):

```
<input command1 | command2 | … | commandN >output
```

If each command is designed (and configured with proper options+operands) to read from its stdin and write to its stdout then data will flow from `input` to `output`. Each command will do something to the data stream (in this context "no change" is also "something") and pass it further down the pipeline. This way you can chain many "effects" that affect data. Commands working like this are called filters (especially when they process text data).

In Unix philosophy a tool should do one thing and do it well. The idea is to use many simple, well defined tools to achieve what you want. Often it means to chain many filters to get a complex filter.

On the other end of the spectrum there's a situation where the number of commands is one. You can have just one command reading from `input`, doing something and writing to `output`:

```
<input command1 >output
# or equivalently
command1 <input >output
# or (extra spaces allowed)
command1 < input > output
```

Again, the command needs to be designed to work like this. Many are, some are not. Some commands read from their stdin if you don't specify a path to any input file (as a command line operand) or the path specified is literally `-` ([a convention](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16364/108618)). Read the respective documentation to learn how a particular command behaves.

---

The command in question

> ```
> pv < /dev/sdX > /dev/sdY
> ```

is equivalent to

```
</dev/sdX pv >/dev/sdY
```

and `pv` is designed to work like this. You may have thought `< /dev/sdX >` is some form (syntax) of providing the `/dev/sdX` operand to `pv`. It's not. `< /dev/sdX` and `> /dev/sdY` are two separate redirections, the actual command is sole `pv` without arguments.

Thanks to how `pv` is able to work with its stdin and stdout, the whole line means "read from `/dev/sdX`, do something to the data stream (whatever `pv` does) and write to `/dev/sdY`".

`pv` would also understand this:

```
pv /dev/sdX >/dev/sdY
```

In this case `/dev/sdX` is a command line argument to `pv`. The tool will read from the specified file and ignore its stdin (only because it's designed to work this way), so the effect will basically be the same.

Your goal is to clone, so the desired "something to do" is "no change"; you want to "read from `/dev/sdX`, change nothing and write to `/dev/sdY`". The most basic program (command) that does "no change" is `cat`. Why `pv` then?

There are *many* commands that can do "no change". For a particular command the ability to perform "no change" may be because:

- "no change" is a special case of the task the command is designed to do ("do one thing and do it well", remember?); with proper options (or lack of them) the task becomes "no change";
- the command is designed to pass data unchanged while doing another thing on the side; this may be:
- forking the data stream,
- providing a buffer (in memory or on disk),
- affecting throughput,
- showing throughput, progress or other statistics (via a separate channel: standard error, stderr, so this doesn't interfere with stdout), or logging to a file,
- something else.

---

Examples of commands that perform "no change":

- `</dev/sdX cat >/dev/sdY`

The main purpose of `cat` is to concatenate many files (data streams). When there is no file specified (like in this case), stdin is used. When there is just one input stream, you get "no change".

- `</dev/sdX tee >/dev/sdY`

The main purpose of `tee` is to fork the stream. One copy gets to stdout and each specified file gets a copy as well. When there is no file specified (like in this case), you get just one copy to stdout, "no change".

- `</dev/sdX dd >/dev/sdY`

`dd` is a common tool for cloning block devices (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1114763/432690)), but [there are quirks](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/432690). Traditionally one would use `if=/dev/sdX` and `of=/dev/sdY`, without them stdin and stdout are used respectively. And you want to use `bs=` for performance. Some options or circumstances may make the output stream differ from the input, still usually you get "no change" (plus some statistics to stderr when `dd` exits).

- `</dev/sdX pv >/dev/sdY`

This will show you progress, throughput. With proper options you can limit the throughput. The data stream is not mangled with, so you get "no change".

- `</dev/sdX mbuffer >/dev/sdY`

Somewhat similar to `pv`, additionally you can choose the size of a buffer it uses (in memory or in a file). The data stream is not mangled with, so you get "no change".

---

Note there is yet another tool that can "read from `input`, change nothing and write to `output`. It's `cp`. Normally you specify the files like this:

```
cp input output
```

This may be not obvious but `cp` can clone `/dev/sdX` to `/dev/sdY`:

```
cp /dev/sdX /dev/sdY
```

The tool is not designed to use its stdin or stdout, it needs paths. This will not work:

```
</dev/sdX cp >/dev/sdY
```

In modern Linux you can make `cp` use its stdin and stdout like this:

```
<input cp /dev/stdin /dev/stdout >output
# or
<input cp /proc/self/fd/0 /proc/self/fd/1 >output
```

Where `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/stdout` link to `/proc/self/fd/0` and `/proc/self/fd/1` respectively. These are special files provided by the kernel. If any process tries to open `/proc/self/fd/0`, it will get its own stdin. Similarly with `/proc/self/fd/1` and stdout. This way you can force some not-pipeline-friendly processes to work with redirections or in a pipeline. It's hardly ever useful and there may be some problems (usually commands are not-pipeline-friendly for reasons), I won't elaborate.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed !  (I am more advanced than the first part but the extra clarity of the explaination made me learn new things any way)
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

The command [`pv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv):

> pv - monitor the progress of data through a pipe
>
> To use it, insert it in a pipeline between two processes, with the appropriate options. Its standard input will be passed through to its standard output and progress will be shown on standard error.

With `< /dev/sdX` meaning to redirect standard input to `/dev/sdX` and `> /dev/sdY` redirecting the output to `sdY`

The `pv` command is simply piping data from one device to another with the following addition

> **progress will be shown on standard error.**

I.e. your console, as `standard error` has not been redirected.

`pv` is not a command for timing anything, it is to monitor data passing through. If it has access to information about how much data there is then it can *in theory* work out how long it might take.

[`time`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) is used to time things.

Answer (score 0):

- `<` redirects standard input
- `>` redirects standard output

That command takes /dev/sdX as input (the raw USB device) and writtes into /dev/sdY the new larger USB pen. This will recreate even the partition table (usually located in the first sector) and the partition content from the original pen.